# Mist (0.9.1) cannot detect web3 installed using npm install

Tags: web3js, mist

I have googled a couple of days without finding the answer to my problem.
I installed the newest version of Mist (v. 0.9.1). I read that web3.js is not provided with the release, therefore I installed it using npm (I set the npm directory in the home directory.

In order to see if all went right I ran the automated tests (Develop > Run Tests). 
In the screenshot it seems clear that the problem is the fact that Mist cannot find the web3 javascript package:
[image]
There are also other test that fails, but all are related to web3.
If you click on the tests, you can also see the js-code that fails.

Does anyone know how to fix it or can suggest a detailed guide?

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you solve this ?

Comment: Thank you for reporting. The problem seems open: I found this issue on the [mist repo](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/3222).

Comment: I had a similar issue with REMIX in a local etheruem network. And I solved by using http instead of https. Maybe it is correlated, but I'm not sure.